# Do i need to check whether the phone is in offline mode in every time a new activity is called?

Tags: java, android, oop

I have written a code to check whether the phone is currently online or not. But my question is do i need to check whether the phone is in offline mode in every time a new activity is called? if yes then what is the better way to code that?

The code to check whether phone is online or offline is like this:

```
    private boolean isOnline() {
      ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo nwrkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      if (nwrkInfo != null && nwrkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
}
```

The above code will return true when the phone is online otherwise false. Is there any oops technique so that i can access this method from other activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any oops technique so that i can access this method from
>   other activity?

You can create a Utility class, and declare this method isOnline() as a static function over there (protected or public depending on your package design).

```
protected static boolean isOnline()
```

From any activity call it like this

```
boolean isPhoneOnline = Utility.isOnline();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you give elaborate by giving a sample code if possible? Thanks

Comment: Something like this -
public class Utility
{
 protected static boolean isOnline()
 {
  // Your code
 }
}

While calling from any other class - Utility.isOnline();